# Rounding glitch in javascript, returning 4000%

Tags: javascript

I am trying to measure the percentage of the amount of enemies in a javascript game I am developing.

```
Math.round(10000000 / V.S * 100) / 100
```

This code works fine when V.S is over 1 million, however returns observed values such as 3400% when V.S is around the thousands, but this should be about 0.01%.

V.S is the amount of enemies

10 million is the amount of enemies needed to make you lose the game

I want to show the percentage between the amount currently and the amount needed to lose the game.
How can I make it show that?

Comment: Humm... `Math.round(10000000 / V.S * 100) / 100` = `Math.round(10000000 / V.S)` no ?

Comment: what is the range of values of `V.S` ?

Comment: I think you should use a different variable name instead of `V.S` . That doesn't look like valid javascript.

Comment: "the percentage of the amount of enemies"... as compared to what? Is 10 million supposed to be 100%?

Comment: @PaulRad Not quite. `Math.round(10000000 / V.S * 100) / 100` = `Math.round(1000000000 / V.S) / 100`, but just removing the `* 100` and `/ 100` affects the rounding. For example: `Math.round(1.556 * 100) / 100` = 1.56, but `Math.round(1.556)` = 2.

Comment: @D3EP4K: Sure it's valid. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I'm talking about javascript variable syntax.

Comment: What does "percentage of the amount of enemies" mean in other words?

Comment: @D3EP4K `V.S` is perfectly valid. `V = { S : 100 }`... how would you get the S property from that for example?

Comment: Yeah!! that way it is correct. +1 for that.

Comment: I think this is more of a logic issue than a rounding issue. Seeing 3400% is expected with your current code as it's going to get larger the smaller the input variable is because you're dividing 10mil by the input variable. Any number bigger than 10mil will be less than 1, and anything smaller than 10mil will be bigger than 1.

Comment: In your formula, what does 1 million even mean? What are you trying to do?? Why are you dividing 1000000 by V.S? What's V.S. mean? Why are you multiplying 100 then dividing by 100 after that? What are you doing??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> V.S is the amount of enemies
>
> 10 million is the amount of enemies needed to make you lose the game

Your current code yields how many times `V.S` goes into 10 million

> I want to show the percentage between the amount currently and the
>   amount needed to lose the game.

If you want to know what percentage of the 10 million has shown up:

```
var pctShown = V.S/100000; //or Math.round(V.S/100000) if you want only whole pcts
```

(note: reduction of dividing by 10,000,000 then * 100 to get a pct representation)

If you want the percent remaining, simply find the inverse:

```
var pctRemaining = 100 - V.S/100000; //or again Math.round(100 - V.S/100000)
```